# WPF DataGrid update entire row when single property changes

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, wpfdatagrid

I have been looking into how to format content in a WPF DataGrid on a cell-by-cell basis. [This article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/683429/Guide-to-WPF-DataGrid-formatting-using-bindings) provides what I have found to be the best explanation of how to achieve this.

However; I have used the aforementioned binding example and explored how it works but when you change the text field, it doesn't trigger the converters which display the numeric values to re-fetch their values; vice versa, when you change the numeric fields, it doesn't trigger the text field converters to re-fetch their values, despite using an `CollectionViewSource`.

I have also tried using an `ObservableCollection` which implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`; this still only triggers the bindings for the cell which has been updated to re-fetch their values and not the values for the whole row.

I know `Items.Refresh()` will work and will cause the bindings to be updated for all columns but this should not be necessary every time a cell value is committed; it should be done properly through the bindings; also calling `Items.Refresh()` is very slow and performs far too much unnecessary work.

If the format of a cell is bound using a converter which uses an object rather than just the field value to which it's bound (and the value the converter returns can therefore be influenced by the value of properties in the object other than the one to which the cell is directly bound) how do you get the whole row to update its bindings when any of the cells change value?

Comment: Every property to which you are bound needs to implement INotifyPropertyChanged for the binding to update. You say the underlying model is implementing INotifyPropertyChanged, but I currently don't see a way xcml would know about that from your provided code.

Comment: Thanks for your comment and for your feedback. I've updated the question with the relevant information from the underlying object that I'm using and also shown the method where I'm setting the object value and firing off NotifyPropertyChanged events for multiple fields in an attempt to get them all to update and where it's only working for the property that has actually changed.

Comment: I doubt that it's a problem with WPF not updating the values as described in that article. Could you post the xaml implementing the actual data grid with the value bindings? Also, have you checked the Output window (assuming you're using Visual Studio) for binding errors?

Comment: @dktaylor I've checked the output window and there's nothing I can see beyond a minor issue with the MultiBinding which is trying to set the target properties against all of the items within the MultiBinding; but only one of the parameters needs / has that property. I would not have thought that would stop all of the other bindings refreshing, though. I will try and post the XAML implementing the actual grid but because the columns are dynamic based on the object you pass to it, there's code behind gong on; and the question is already quite tl;dr as it is!

Comment: @dktaylor I've overhauled the question to make it clearer what it is I'm asking and have got rid of a lot of unnecessary context, to get right to the root of what I'm asking.

Comment: why do you want to update the whole row if only one cell changed? This means that your bindings are wrong. You have to reacalculate values dependig on some property, then they will change properly. Still, you have to show us the code

Comment: @KrzysztofSkowronek Yes I think you're right; the bindings are wrong. Right now the Bindings are bound to the Text Property of the TextBlock in the cell; so I can call the NotifyPropertyChanged event as much as I like on the source object; if it doesn't cause the Text Property to be updated, nothing will trigger. I'm going to re-work the bindings to be bound to the field of the source object rather than the Text property of the TextBlock. If that works I'll post the final implementation.